# Mesh messaging opcodes

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Could you point me the opcodes for various mesh messaging? For example, I see that 0x8201 is the opcode for Generic OnOff get. I would like to see complete list (sensor model messaging etc).

Rgds,
Venkat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full list is available in the [Bluetooth SIG website](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/mesh-specifications). Please have a look in the [Mesh Model Specification v1.0.1](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=457091), Chapter 7: Summary, Section 7.1: Table Summary (page 301 of 307).